# Why python-vlc mediaplayer doesn't work with url from list?

Tags: python, python-vlc

I tried to build a small webradio with pyhton-vlc. When I directly write the url of the radiostream in the code everything works fine. But I would like to read the urls from the "radiostationen.txt". But when I replace the hard coded url with the first entry of the urls list I get the following error from the vlc-media-player: "VLC is unable to open the MRL 'https://stream.liferadio.tirol/live/mp3-192".

The python code:

```
import vlc
import keyboard

volume = 10

with open('radiostationen.txt') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

url = urls[0]

instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen')
player=instance.media_player_new()
media=instance.media_new(url)
media.get_mrl()
player.audio_set_volume(volume)
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
```

The radiostationen.txt:

```
https://stream.liferadio.tirol/live/mp3-192
https://orf-live.ors-shoutcast.at/tir-q2a
https://orf-live.ors-shoutcast.at/fm4-q2a
```

If I use `url = "https://stream.liferadio.tirol/live/mp3-192"` instead of `url = urls[0]` it works.

Also the link in the error works.

Comment: `readlines` retains the newline character (`\n`) at the end of each entry in its returned value. Does `url = urls[0].rstrip()` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readline` and `readlines` methods [retain the newline character](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) (`\n`) at the end of the lines they read.

You need to strip off this character before passing the URL to VLC, e.g. `url = urls[0][:-1]` or `url = urls[0].rstrip()` should work.